# If $\kappa$ is ineffable, then there is no $\kappa$-Kurepa tree

Tags: set-theory, large-cardinals, infinitary-combinatorics

So this is an exercise($4.25$) from Ralf Schindler's book, and I have some trouble with it.

This is the statement:

> (**Jensen-Kunen**) Show that if $\kappa$ is ineffable, then there is no $\kappa$-Kurepa tree.

So naturally after thinking about this for some time, I decided to take a peek at its solution for a hint.

First I found [this](https://blog.assafrinot.com/?p=1964) in Assaf Rinot's webpage. But there he proves this for slim $\kappa$-Kurepa trees. Then I tried to find the main paper where Jensen and Kunen first proved this. But all I found was an unpublished manuscript in Jensen's webpage, which was extremely hard to read for me and even there it seems that the result is proved for slim $\kappa$-Kurepa trees as well, even though they don't mention it.

[This](http://www.mathematik.hu-berlin.de/~raesch/org/jensen.html) is a link to Jensen's webpage. The unpublished paper is called "Some Combinatorial Properties of $L$ and $V$". The result is in page $26$ of the second chapter, it's theorem $9$.

So my question is: Is the above statement correct for general $\kappa$-Kurepa trees? If so, how would one prove it?

Comment: A small side question: when reading the text from Jensen, he used the word Mahlo instead of stationary, at least I think so. Is this correct? Meaning: did people call stationary sets, Mahlo sets in the past? Or does it have some added meaning?

Comment: Mahlo is defined at the bottom of page 1 of Chapter 1 of the handwritten notes you mentioned and its definition does agree with that of a stationary set. I have no idea how common this terminology was in the past though

Comment: @AlessandroCodenotti, Ah thanks. I skipped the first chapter. It's really hard to both decode the text and the mathematics. :)

Comment: Also some slimness condition is necessary, otherwise if $\kappa$ is strong limit then the full binary tree of height $\kappa$ is a $\kappa$-Kurepa tree

Comment: @AlessandroCodenotti, Oh, you are completely right. So we have to restrict everything in order to avoid these trivial cases. I would be more than happy if you turned your comment to an answer, so I could accept it. Also it would take this question off of the unanswered list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that whenever $\kappa$ is a strong limit cardinal (and of course ineffable cardinals are strong limit) there is a $\kappa$-Kurepa tree, namely the full binary tree of height $\kappa$, where by $\kappa$-Kurepa tree I mean a tree of height $\kappa$, such that all levels have size $<\kappa$ but the tree has at least $\kappa^+$ branches.

So either Schindler's book has the slimness condition in the definition of a $\kappa$-Kurepa tree or the exercise has a typo, but I'm not familiar with the book so I can't tell. I see that you already found a proof of the fact that if $\kappa$ is ineffable then there is no slim $\kappa$-Kurepa tree, you can also look at [theorem 2.6 here](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.pl/1235419485), this pdf also seems to cover more of the results contained in Jensen's handwritten notes if you're interested.

Comment: Since the definition has no slimness condition, I guess it's just a typo. I really appreciate the pdf, although it doesn't open for me, I do have a copy of Devlin's book. Thanks!